# PostgreSQL - PhpMyAdmin, error with BLOB type

Tags: postgresql, phpmyadmin

This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
 Id int PRIMARY KEY,
 Image LONGBLOB
 );
```

It doesn't work, neither with `BLOB`, `LONGBLOB`, `MEDIUMBLOB` etc.
PhpMyAdmin tells me this:

ERROR: Type "longblob" doesn't exist

SQL state: 42704

Character: 57

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your query worked fine for me, what version of MySQL and PHPMyAdmin are you using?

Comment: PHPMyAdmin: 1.22.1
PostgreSQL: 9.5.1
I've made an error, I'm not using MySQL but PostgreSQL.

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't have these data types. How can you use PHPMyAdmin with PostgreSQL?

Comment: I don't remember how, I installed it under directions of my teacher a year ago.
By the way, thank you, I'll search a corresponding type in PostreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, the problem is that I was using a type that doesn't exist in PostgreSQL.

The type `BLOB` (and derivatives) from MySQL can be substituted with `BYTEA` in PostgreSQL.
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Converting_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL